# Is there any way to check which baud rates are supported on a serial device?

Tags: linux, serial-port

Is there any way to check which baud rates are supported for a serial device on Linux?

I've poked around the `/sys/class/tty/ttyS0` directory, but I can't see anything in there that lists this type of information.

Comment: I would hesitate to say it's available unless the driver controlling the device is 100% compatible. I'd go to the manufacturer's documentation to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different questions.

> Is there any way to check which baud rates are supported on a serial device?

The answer would depend on (1) the capabilities of the hardware, i.e. the UART/USART/SCC,  and the range of divisors that the device driver can use in the baud rate generator; consult the device data sheet; (2) the frequency of the clock/oscillator connected to the serial port device; consult the board documentation.

> Is there any way to check which baud rates are supported on Linux?

The one of the defined baud rates in `include/asm-generic/termbits.h` for the *c_cflag* member of the terminal control structure is the typical method that the serial port (i.e. UART/USART) device driver receives for the baud rate configuration value.

```
#define  B0     0000000         /* hang up */
#define  B50    0000001
#define  B75    0000002
#define  B110   0000003
#define  B134   0000004
#define  B150   0000005
#define  B200   0000006
#define  B300   0000007
#define  B600   0000010
#define  B1200  0000011
#define  B1800  0000012
#define  B2400  0000013
#define  B4800  0000014
#define  B9600  0000015
#define  B19200 0000016
#define  B38400 0000017

#define    BOTHER 0010000
#define    B57600 0010001
#define   B115200 0010002
#define   B230400 0010003
#define   B460800 0010004
#define   B500000 0010005
#define   B576000 0010006
#define   B921600 0010007
#define  B1000000 0010010
#define  B1152000 0010011
#define  B1500000 0010012
#define  B2000000 0010013
#define  B2500000 0010014
#define  B3000000 0010015
#define  B3500000 0010016
#define  B4000000 0010017
```

Serial port drivers typically do not have any means of reporting/advertising which of these baud rates are actually supported/configurable/implemented.  There is a capabilities value for attributes like FIFO and sleeping but not for baud rates.  A driver could define an *ioctl()* call to configure (nonstandard) baud rates, although that would make programs using it non-portable.

Comment: I just realize that I've missed to tell you that  your answer was cited in [mine](https://superuser.com/a/1482079/178656), posted 7 years later (3 years ago).

Answer (score 19):

#### New version august 2023:

As new source tree has splitted `termbits.h` into `termbits-common.h` and `termbits.h`

## Little [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

From [sawdust's answer](https://superuser.com/a/488721), there is my solution:

```bash
for bauds in $(
    sed -r 's/^#define\s+B([1-9][0-9]+)\s+.*/\1/p;d' \
        /usr/include/asm-generic/termbits*.h ) ;do
    echo $bauds
    stty -F /dev/ttyS0 $bauds && echo Ok.
done  2>&1 |
    pr -at2
```

Will render on my host:

```
50                              Ok.
75                              Ok.
110                             Ok.
134                             Ok.
150                             Ok.
200                             Ok.
300                             Ok.
600                             Ok.
1200                                    Ok.
1800                                    Ok.
2400                                    Ok.
4800                                    Ok.
9600                                    Ok.
19200                                   Ok.
38400                                   Ok.
57600                                   Ok.
115200                                  Ok.
230400                                  Ok.
460800                                  Ok.
500000                                  Ok.
576000                                  Ok.
921600                                  Ok.
1000000                                 Ok.
1152000                                 Ok.
1500000                                 Ok.
2000000                                 stty: /dev/ttyS0: unable to perform
2500000                                 stty: /dev/ttyS0: unable to perform
3000000                                 stty: /dev/ttyS0: unable to perform
3500000                                 stty: /dev/ttyS0: unable to perform
4000000                                 stty: /dev/ttyS0: unable to perform
```

That is, but this won't mean it will work!

You have to test them with your cable and your device...

With cleaner output...

```bash
hfile=(/usr/include/asm-generic/termbits*.h) ans=(yes no);column < <(
    while read -r bauds;do
        stty -F /dev/ttyS0 $bauds &>/dev/null
        printf '%8d %-3s\n' $bauds ${ans[$?]}
    done < <(
  sed -r 's/^#define\s+B([0-9]{2,})\s+.*/\1/p;d' "${hfile[@]}" ))
```

May output something like:

```
      50 yes         300 yes        9600 yes      460800 no      1500000 no 
      75 yes         600 yes       19200 yes      500000 no      2000000 no 
     110 yes        1200 yes       38400 yes      576000 no      2500000 no 
     134 yes        1800 yes       57600 yes      921600 no      3000000 no 
     150 yes        2400 yes      115200 yes     1000000 no      3500000 no 
     200 yes        4800 yes      230400 no      1152000 no      4000000 no
```

#### Listing `tty` devices

Quick device list, by [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) expansion and array manipulation, based on device name.

```bash
devs=(/dev/tty?*) devs=(${devs[@]##*/}) devs=(${devs[@]%tty[0-9]*})
```

But I prefer this: more reliable, based on `/sys` pseudo fs: (100% pure bash)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar extglob
devs=(/sys/devices/!(virtual)/**/device/tty/tty?*)
ans=yes hfile=(/usr/include/asm-generic/termbits*.h)
bauds=()
for file in "${hfile[@]}"; do
    while read -r lhs rhs _ ; do
         case $lhs$rhs in
             \#defineB[0-9]* ) bauds+=(${rhs#B}) ;;
         esac
    done < "$file"
done
declare -A devdone='()'
for tty in "${devs[@]##*/}";do
    if [[ ! -v devdone["$tty"] ]] &&
            read _ oldrate _ < <(stty -F /dev/$tty 2>/dev/null); then
        echo "[ $tty ]"
        for i in ${!bauds[@]}; do
            rate=${bauds[i]}   nc=' '
            (( i == ${#bauds[@]}-1 || ( (1+i) % 6 ) == 0 )) && nc=$'\n'
            stty -F /dev/$tty $rate &> /dev/null
            printf '%8d %-3s%s' $rate ${ans[$?]:-no} "$nc"
        done
        stty -F /dev/$tty $oldrate &>/dev/null
        devdone["$tty"]=yes
    fi
done
```

On my host ( with some Arduinos and ESP32 plugged on my USB ), I see:

```
[ ttyUSB1 ]
       0 no        50 yes       75 yes      110 yes      134 yes      150 yes
     200 yes      300 yes      600 yes     1200 yes     1800 yes     2400 yes
    4800 yes     9600 yes    19200 yes    38400 yes    57600 yes   115200 yes
  230400 yes   460800 yes   500000 yes   576000 yes   921600 yes  1000000 yes
 1152000 yes  1500000 yes  2000000 yes  2500000 yes  3000000 yes  3500000 no 
 4000000 no 
[ ttyUSB2 ]
       0 no        50 yes       75 yes      110 yes      134 yes      150 yes
     200 yes      300 yes      600 yes     1200 yes     1800 yes     2400 yes
    4800 yes     9600 yes    19200 yes    38400 yes    57600 yes   115200 yes
  230400 yes   460800 yes   500000 yes   576000 yes   921600 yes  1000000 yes
 1152000 yes  1500000 yes  2000000 yes  2500000 yes  3000000 yes  3500000 no 
 4000000 no 
[ ttyUSB3 ]
       0 no        50 no        75 no       110 no       134 no       150 no 
     200 no       300 yes      600 yes     1200 yes     1800 yes     2400 yes
    4800 yes     9600 yes    19200 yes    38400 yes    57600 yes   115200 yes
  230400 yes   460800 yes   500000 yes   576000 yes   921600 yes  1000000 yes
 1152000 no   1500000 no   2000000 no   2500000 no   3000000 no   3500000 no 
 4000000 no 
[ ttyS1 ]
       0 no        50 yes       75 yes      110 yes      134 yes      150 yes
     200 yes      300 yes      600 yes     1200 yes     1800 yes     2400 yes
    4800 yes     9600 yes    19200 yes    38400 yes    57600 yes   115200 yes
  230400 no    460800 no    500000 no    576000 no    921600 no   1000000 no 
 1152000 no   1500000 no   2000000 no   2500000 no   3000000 no   3500000 no 
 4000000 no 
[ ttyS0 ]
       0 no        50 yes       75 yes      110 yes      134 yes      150 yes
     200 yes      300 yes      600 yes     1200 yes     1800 yes     2400 yes
    4800 yes     9600 yes    19200 yes    38400 yes    57600 yes   115200 yes
  230400 no    460800 no    500000 no    576000 no    921600 no   1000000 no 
 1152000 no   1500000 no   2000000 no   2500000 no   3000000 no   3500000 no 
 4000000 no
```

### Important remark:

Having *port* configurable to any speed doesn't mean that *target device* could support this!!

In my dump, the two 1st USB are arduinos and the last *`ttyUSB3`* is an ESP32. And I know I could work at `921'600` with `ESP32`, but a can't communicate with Arduino with a higher baud rate than `115'200`! Even if port if configurable to a max of `3'000'000` bauds!!

Comment: This is amazing. For anyone wondering, be sure to update `/dev/ttyS0` in the script to the path to your currently-plugged-in USB UART device!

Comment: @GabrielStaples New version scanning  `/dev`!

Comment: Thank you. I have added a script containing your code to my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here: [serial_list_bauds.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/serial_list_bauds.sh). To list all baud rates of ALL devices, run `serial_list_bauds`, and to list all baud rates of just `/dev/ttyUSB0`, run `serial_list_bauds /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples [Give Up GitHub](https://sfconservancy.org/blog/2022/jun/30/give-up-github-launch/)!!! ( And consider learning usage  of [GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)! Lot more than just an IDE ;-)

Comment: Ah, right, I had seen your name and read your profile description before about how you hate GitHub. Regarding Emacs, what gives it away that I'm not using it?

Comment: @GabrielStaples There are no mention of  `GNU Emacs` in your `useful_apps/README.md`, but point `#14` do suggest anther *text editor* ;-)

Comment: I see. Eclipse is _horribly heavy_, but has the world's greatest indexer for navigating multi-million-line code bases easier. I mostly use Sublime Text, ripgrep, fzf, etc, these days. Regarding GitHub, I side with GitHub. Companies making money from FOSS software is critically important. https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html Additionally, their ML models trained on open source software is fine, the same as when someone's proprietary program communicates with my GPL program through my ABI (command-line interface). I hope they make not just millions, but **billions** of $$, & give back.

Comment: ... And I don't *hate* Github, I'm just afraid by his new proprietary tools around github stuff, (your work become dealable, by using dedicated IA...)! I *hate* de new holder of Github, not Github himself, but seeing how this **open** plateform are evolving, **human** developers are urged to leaving this sh#*t quickly!.

Comment: And you are right: I should learn a command-line editor; ex: emacs, vim. The gain vs pain ratio hasn't yet weighed strong enough in that favor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139787/discussion-between-f-hauri-give-up-github-and-gabriel-staples).

Comment: @GabrielStaples New serial device list, based on `/sys` fs.

Answer (score 9):

You can check the device baud rate using the "stty" command on the console:

```
$ stty < /dev/tty..      (where tty... is the device file you are listening)
```

output:

```
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

You can also change the baud rate with the following command:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/tty... 9600    (or whatever baud rate number)
```

Comment: On a Mac (likely also FreeBSD), use `stty -f /dev/tty...` instead.